# detect specific localNotification opened

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, location, uilocalnotification

I am scheduling timer and sending some local notification for user about some data, example is - if there is some store near.

```
func configureNotification(shop: Shop) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
    notification.alertBody = "There is a store \(shop.name) near!"//Localized().near_shop_string + shopName
    notification.alertAction = "Swipe to see offer!"//Localized().swipe_to_see_string
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

When app running in background if there is some store near users coordinates, there is a local notification.

For example, there is three local notification received about different stores and user swipes the second one and make app active from it.

The question is, to recognize from what specific notification  applicationDidBecomeActive was launched, some launcOptions, as for push notifications from server? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need handle it in `didReceiveLocalNotification` delegate method

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification!) {
        // do your jobs here
}
```

`notification` param will contain info for every notification.

Also `launchOptions` has a key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` that contains notification.

You can get it like

```
let localNotification:UILocalNotification = launchOptions.objectForKey(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey)
```

Comment: ok, cool, i will receive 3 notifications, and handle them there, but how I can know from what specific notification application became active?

Comment: launch options are available from method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
if application wasn't closed, just send to background, this method is not executed

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification is executed when app become active from local notification?

Comment: So didReceiveLocalNotification will handle after you open app from notification and it will become active. If you need handle after app just open again. You will not handle it.

Comment: Yes it will execute